# use paginate with has in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

I'm trying to get result from query
using paginate and in view using code below i reduce the code to make it accepted
$categories=Course_category::has('classe')->paginate(2);

```
 @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
 @foreach ($categorie->classe as $item )
 @endforeach
 @endforeach
 {{ $categories->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}
```

Comment: Do you have Course_category that have classes?

Comment: In the `AppServiceProvider.php` in the `boot()` method, you can add this: `Paginator::$defaultView = 'pagination::bootstrap-4';` where Paginator comes from `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`

Comment: @workservice yes actualy it return 3 result but when i use pagination doesn't work

Comment: Can you try only this on your blade ? `{{ $categories->links() }}`

Comment: @workservice it returns Class 'App\Providers\Paginator' not found

Comment: @workservice nothing change

Comment: Can you share the whole method on your controller and all the blade?

Comment: @workservice   $categories=Course_category::has('classe')->paginate(2);
        $courses=Course_category_Classe::all();
        return view('teacher.courses')->with(['courses'=>$courses,'categories'=>$categories]);

Comment: blade is too long for comment

Comment: @moussa dont post long code as comment, [edit] and attach it on your question. Also mention your laravel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
$categories = Course_category::with(['classe' => function ($q) {
            $q->paginate(2);
            //or something like $q->orderBy(stuff)->take(2);
        }]);
```

Comment: thank you i tried this  and it work fine $categories=Course_category::with(['classe' => function($q) use($user) {
            $q->where('classe_id', $user->classe_id);
        }])
        ->paginate(1);

Answer (score 2):

if this happen as a result of using bootstrap as paginator
add this to the following director

**App/Provider/AppServiceProveider.php**

**use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;** <!-- add this file to the head of the

```html
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator; //add this too

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap(); //this is the bootstrap code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant this:

```
$categories = Course_category::with(['classe'])->paginate(2);
```

Comment: the same result